# Why does integer division truncates to 0 rather than negative infinity?

Tags: language-agnostic, integer, programming-languages, language-lawyer, language-design

It's a well-known inconsistency in integer division, as defined in C and many other programming languages: division by an integer N yield a remainder in the range 0..N rather than 0..|N|. IMO this negatively affects some applications, for example if you are displaying an image defined by on an integer grid you'd better put (0,0) outside the image area: otherwise you'll get a visible line at x==0 and another one at y==0 on some image operations.

Could you name an example of a practical integer division usage where truncation to 0 would serve the programming intent better than truncation to negative infinity?

Comment: Your first question solicits answers that will be based primarily on opinion. Your second question is IMHO too broad. A little more effort and you'll have a nice little trifecta.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, aye-aye, Captain.

Comment: This wasn't required behavior in ancient C or C++ until recently -- before that both the direction of rounding and the sign of the remainder were unspecified, although they were required to match -- so you may wish to review the notes introducing that change.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a question of programming language design, really.

High level programming languages truncate for consistency with low-level languages.

Low level languages truncate because that's what the hardware operation does.

Later generations of hardware chose to be backward compatible with early generations.

To really answer this question you have to go waaaaay back, and the reason could be as subtle as "it made a carry chain shorter".

Please note, though, that any other choice breaks distributivity:

```
// both of these are true if integer division truncates toward zero, else uncertain
-1 * b / c == -1 * (b / c)
-1 * b % c == -1 * (b % c) % c
```

are rather nice identities to preserve.

Comment: The legacy explanation answers the question: one of those convenient-at-the-time shortcuts that have unfortunately become carved in stone. However, I would find the "distributivity" explanation more interesting if it was true. It's not true though: try -2*-2/-3.

Comment: @Michael: Err, yeah.  I was thinking about `a = -1` when I wrote that, and didn't test whether it actually would generalize.

Comment: +1  (I'm old enough to remember when you were lucky if your computer did integer division in hardware at all.)

Comment: I think you answer is good.  There is an additional fact.  A compiler may strength reduce things.  For instance say N is 8, a compiler may just right shift.  There are other identities that may reduce the strength of a *division* to some simpler and faster math operations.

Comment: @artlessnoise: Strength reduction is really beside the point.  Unless a language is implemented so that no integer division operation uses the hardware instruction for integer division, then the behavior of that hardware instruction is going to surface.

Comment: By truncating to zero you can use right shifts to encode long division by a constant.  Another operation will be to transform a division to a *multiply and shift*.  On some CPUs, the shift comes for free.  You miss all these strength reductions if you don't truncate to zero.  Some CPUs don't even have a hardware divide.  The *strength reductions* are often portions of doing [long division](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55951.html), which a library may do in the absence of a hw division.

Comment: @artlessnoise: I'm not convinced that the strength reductions would be totally impossible with different rounding, since rounding can be fixed up with fairly cheap operations, but you definitely do provide a strong case for improved efficiency with truncation.